# Strange crash on ARM and Intel

Tags: c++, assembly, crash, memory-corruption

Haters gonna hate, but I can not provide source code for this problem, since I can not separate the issue, but I will try to provide as much information as I can.

So my problem is, that a my application crashes in well defined circumstances, at a well defined point in a C++ library that I use (OpenCASCADE).

1. The crash only occurs, when I run the code from a new thread
2. There is no shared data between the threads
3. The crash occurs in a method call, before the first instruction in the method runs. Here is a dissassambly:

   `` Shapr3D`GeomInt_ParFunctionOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::Perform(math_Vector const&) at AppParCurves_Function.gxx:262:
   0x10b5701b0:  pushq  %rbp
   0x10b5701b1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x10b5701b4:  subq   $0x663e0, %rsp
   0x10b5701bb:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
   0x10b5701bf:  movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
   0x10b5701c3:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rsi
   0x10b5701c7:  movq   %rsi, %rdi
   0x10b5701ca:  addq   $0xc0, %rdi
   0x10b5701d1:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rax
   0x10b5701d5:  movq   %rsi, -0x65ba0(%rbp)   //Crashes here
   0x10b5701dc:  movq   %rax, %rsi
   0x10b5701df:  callq  0x10c050d76               ; symbol stub for:           math_Vector::operator=(math_Vector const&)
   0x10b5701e4:  movq   -0x65ba0(%rbp), %rsi
   0x10b5701eb:  addq   $0x8828, %rsi
   0x10b5701f2:  movq   -0x65ba0(%rbp), %rdi
   0x10b5701f9:  addq   $0xc0, %rdi
   0x10b570200:  movq   %rdi, -0x65ba8(%rbp)
   0x10b570207:  movq   %rsi, %rdi
   0x10b57020a:  movq   -0x65ba8(%rbp), %rsi
   0x10b570211:  movq   %rax, -0x65bb0(%rbp) ``
4. It crashes with bad access: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9f1606100)
5. It does not matter whether the object that the method called on is dynamically or statically allocated
6. I provided Intel disassempbly, but the crash occurs both on Mac OS and iOS, 32 and 64 bit
7. Valgrind did not reveal any issues
8. Also, here is a callstack (this is probably not very useful, unless you are familiar with OpenCASCADE)

`0   0x000000010b5701d5 in GeomInt_ParFunctionOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::Perform(math_Vector const&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Function.gxx:265
1   0x000000010b574dac in GeomInt_ParFunctionOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::Values(math_Vector const&, double&, math_Vector&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Function.gxx:589
2   0x000000010b790286 in math_BFGS::Perform(math_MultipleVarFunctionWithGradient&, math_Vector const&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/math/math_BFGS.cxx:187
3   0x000000010b56934c in GeomInt_Gradient_BFGSOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::GeomInt_Gradient_BFGSOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox(math_MultipleVarFunctionWithGradient&, math_Vector const&, double, double, double, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Gradient_BFGS.gxx:31
4   0x000000010b5693c9 in GeomInt_Gradient_BFGSOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::GeomInt_Gradient_BFGSOfMyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox(math_MultipleVarFunctionWithGradient&, math_Vector const&, double, double, double, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Gradient_BFGS.gxx:32
5   0x000000010b56c80d in GeomInt_MyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::GeomInt_MyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox(GeomInt_TheMultiLineOfWLApprox const&, int, int, Handle_AppParCurves_HArray1OfConstraintCouple const&, math_Vector&, int, double, double, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Gradient.gxx:186
6   0x000000010b56cd4a in GeomInt_MyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::GeomInt_MyGradientOfTheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox(GeomInt_TheMultiLineOfWLApprox const&, int, int, Handle_AppParCurves_HArray1OfConstraintCouple const&, math_Vector&, int, double, double, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/AppParCurves_Gradient.gxx:209
7   0x000000010b5a67c9 in GeomInt_TheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::Compute(GeomInt_TheMultiLineOfWLApprox const&, int, int, math_Vector&, double&, double&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/Approx_ComputeLine.gxx:920
8   0x000000010b5a5704 in GeomInt_TheComputeLineBezierOfWLApprox::Perform(GeomInt_TheMultiLineOfWLApprox const&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/Approx_ComputeLine.gxx:779
9   0x000000010b5c4f79 in GeomInt_WLApprox::Perform(IntSurf_Quadric const&, Handle_Adaptor3d_HSurface const&, Handle_IntPatch_WLine const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/ApproxInt_Approx.gxx:1058
10  0x000000010b5c359f in GeomInt_WLApprox::Perform(Handle_Adaptor3d_HSurface const&, Handle_Adaptor3d_HSurface const&, Handle_IntPatch_WLine const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/ApproxInt_Approx.gxx:637
11  0x000000010bd61455 in IntTools_FaceFace::MakeCurve(int, Handle_Adaptor3d_TopolTool const&, Handle_Adaptor3d_TopolTool const&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/IntTools/IntTools_FaceFace.cxx:1839
12  0x000000010bd58cae in IntTools_FaceFace::Perform(TopoDS_Face const&, TopoDS_Face const&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/IntTools/IntTools_FaceFace.cxx:749
13  0x000000010bccb172 in BOPAlgo_FaceFace::Perform() at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/BOPAlgo/BOPAlgo_PaveFiller_6.cxx:156
14  0x000000010bccab56 in BOPCol_Functor >::operator()(int) const at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/BOPCol_Parallel.hxx:45
15  0x000000010bcca8f2 in void OSD_Parallel::For > >(int, int, BOPCol_Functor > const&, unsigned int) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/OSD_Parallel.hxx:262
16  0x000000010bcc4d2b in BOPCol_Cnt >, BOPCol_NCVector >::Perform(unsigned int, BOPCol_NCVector&) at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/adm/mac/xcd/../../../inc/BOPCol_Parallel.hxx:68
17  0x000000010bcb9cef in BOPAlgo_PaveFiller::PerformFF() at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/BOPAlgo/BOPAlgo_PaveFiller_6.cxx:270
18  0x000000010bca41c3 in BOPAlgo_PaveFiller::PerformInternal() at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/BOPAlgo/BOPAlgo_PaveFiller.cxx:303
19  0x000000010bca3d6d in BOPAlgo_PaveFiller::Perform() at /Users/icsanady/occt_git/occt/src/BOPAlgo/BOPAlgo_PaveFiller.cxx:203`

I know it is really hard to help without having the source, but currently this is the best I can provide, and I am really stuck. I hope someone at least can give me some hints. I will try to provide any information that is necessary.

Comment: Out of stackspace? The function for which you posted dissassembly uses about 400KB of stack, which is way more than your should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method makes a large allocation on the stack with:

```
0x10b5701b4:  subq   $0x663e0, %rsp
```

and your app crashed while storing to the stack with:

```
0x10b5701d5:  movq   %rsi, -0x65ba0(%rbp)   //Crashes here
```

(It's using **RBP** as the frame pointer)

Thus I suspect a stack overflow. Try [increasing the stack size for this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435087/how-to-set-pthread-max-stack-size). Note that `0x663e0` is 418784 bytes and that really is an unusually large amount of stack to be using.

Comment: Thank you scottt, you are probably right. Do you have any idea, how can I debug what is causing the big allocation of the stack? Here you can check the source: https://bitbucket.org/istvancsanady/occt/src/580f5d5257675e534060d1391ebda21d446ff18c/src/AppParCurves/AppParCurves_Function.gxx?at=iOS#cl-262

Comment: @IstvánCsanády, try disassembling the method in mixed source / asm format, i.e. `(gdb) disassemble /m LONG-METHOD-NAME`.

Comment: You were right, the problem was that matrices and vectors were allocated statically. Thank you for helping me even without source code.